# Primefaces p:ajax disabled attribute doesn't work

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm working with JSF 2.2 (MyFaces) and Primefaces 5. The `disabled` attribute of `p:ajax` component in a `p:datatable` doesn't work.

```
<p:dataTable id="transactionListTable"
   value="#{cardsTransactionsList}"
    var="transaction" 
    selectionMode="single"
    rowExpandMode="single" >

    <p:ajax event="rowSelect"
     disabled="#{condition}"
    listener="#{cardTransactionsListCBean.onRowSelect}"
    update=":cardsForm:transactionListTable" />
```

If `disabled` has value `true` the ajax call is not disabled. I want disable the row expansion feature when `condition` is `true`. Some idea, please? Bye.

Comment: First of all, disabling the ajax does not disable the rowexpansion feature itself. And rowExpansion != rowSelect iirc, so maybe the wrong event is used.

Comment: If I click on row, at to `rowSelect` event is invoked the action listener also if  disabled is true